# Failing to write to database using entity framework ( edmx )

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx

As the title says, I have a problem writing to local database. I generated a edmx Model from this, and I can easily read from it.

```
EDMXNS.TOWDataBasev1Entities db = new EDMXNS.TOWDataBasev1Entities();

var query = from p in db.Accounts select p;

foreach (EDMXNS.Accounts s in query)
    Console.WriteLine(s.AccountName);
```

That works fine. However when I try to write to the database, nothing happens. I do not get any errors, exceptions etc. I figure, since I can read from the database, that it's not a connection problem.

Here is the code i have for writing.

```
EDMXNS.TOWDataBasev1Entities db = new EDMXNS.TOWDataBasev1Entities();
EDMXNS.Accounts acc = new EDMXNS.Accounts();

acc.AccountID = 1;
acc.AccountName = "testuser";
acc.AccountPW = "testpw";
acc.PersonDataID = 0;

db.AddToAccounts(acc);
db.SaveChanges();
```

It is worthwhile to meantion that my Accounts.AccountID has identity/autoincrement, but I have tried both setting it to the next known value, or simply not setting it at all.

Do anyone have an idea as to what might cause this problem?

EDIT: I also tried to remove the custom name space, delete all records of the database and reimport it all.

Removing the custom tool name space, results in errors like these:
Ambiguity between 'TOWServer.Accounts.AccountName' and 'TOWServer.Accounts.AccountName'

Which doesnt tell me anything.

Reimporting everything now gives me an exception:
"Unable to load the specified metadata resource"

Comment: I'm a bit new to this. I think its the latest, but how do I see that?

Comment: I also tried  `db.Accounts.AddObject(acc);`  but that didnt work either.

Comment: does it throws any exception? if you put it inside the `try-catch` block, popup the error `MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())`

Comment: Nope, no exception thrown. It does state that .AddToAccounts is deprecated, and that I should use the Add method of the associated object set <T> instead, but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: have you tried `db.Accounts.Add(acc);` ?

Comment: I dont have a db.Accounts.Add method. I only have a .AddObject, and that doesn't work.    Also, my entity framework i found out was v4.0.30319

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21722/discussion-between-user1482794-and-jw)

Answer (score 0):

I've always use this format when adding records with EF, Try following this format:

```
using (MovieStoreEntities context = new MoveStoreEntities()) 
    { 
      try 
      { 

        context.Movies.AddObject(new Movie() { MovieID = 234,  
             Title = "Sleepless Nights in Seattle", Quantity = 10 }); 
        context.SaveChanges(); 
      } 
      catch(Exception ex)  
      { 
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);  
      } 
    }
```

Comment: That didnt work either.  Do you think it might have something to do with me using a custom toolset namespace? EDMXNS.  If i don't use it, I have a name conflict